# rocket.chat hubot is not working for version 6.3.12

Tags: node.js, rocket.chat

i am new to rocket.chat i have deployed the rocket.chat in ec2 ubuntu in aws, its working fine after that i created a custom hubot using  https://github.com/RocketChat/hubot-rocketchat.git and a .env file after that when i run the "bin/hubot" showing the logs as connected but when i see in console it not showing green dot or status as online

but it working for rocket.chat version 5.0.3, i dont know why the bot not works for 6.3.12 version

here is the logs of bot

```
[Tue Feb 06 2024 11:18:52 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)] INFO [startup] Rocket.Chat adapter in use
[Tue Feb 06 2024 11:18:52 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)] INFO [startup] Respond to name: Hubot
[Tue Feb 06 2024 11:18:52 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)] INFO [startup] Respond to alias: mybotuser
[Tue Feb 06 2024 11:18:52 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)] INFO [connect] Connecting {
  username: 'mybotuser',
  password: '123456789',
  ldap: false,
  host: 'https://example.com:443',
  useSsl: true,
  timeout: 20000,
  rooms: [ 'general' ],
  allPublic: true,
  dm: true,
  livechat: true,
  edited: true,
  integrationId: 'js.SDK',
  roomCacheMaxSize: 10,
  roomCacheMaxAge: 300000,
  dmCacheMaxSize: 10,
  dmCacheMaxAge: 100000
}
[Tue Feb 06 2024 11:18:52 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)] INFO [connect] Connected
[Tue Feb 06 2024 11:18:52 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)] INFO [login] Logging in mybotuser
[Tue Feb 06 2024 11:18:52 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)] INFO [subscribe] Preparing subscription: stream-room-messages: __my_messages__
[Tue Feb 06 2024 11:18:52 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)] INFO [subscribe] Stream ready: 2
[Tue Feb 06 2024 11:18:52 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)] INFO [reactive] Listening for change events in collection stream-room-messages
```

Here is the rocket.chat info

```
Version
6.3.12
Apps Engine Version
1.40.0
Node Version
v14.21.3
MongoDB
5.0.23
```

any suggestions that would be helpful for me